# Magento2 : How to remove delete item button from cart page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento2.2.6, delete, cart-items

I want to remove `delete item` button from cart page.

I am using below xml code to remove this but not working:-

Path:

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

Please help me to do this using xml and if my approach is not correct what is the right way to do this.

Comment: even when you try to directly remove that block from this file `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`, it doesn't work.

Comment: your xml code is totally correct and also theme path is correct. i tried in my setup and successfully removed **delete item** button.

Comment: @Naresh but It not working at my end, any help or suggestion, I am using 2.2.6

Comment: also checked with 2.2.9 and working good there

Answer (score 0):

Override **magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\default.phtml** file in your theme at **app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME_NAME\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\default.phtml**

Arround at line no 113 you will find following code

```
<tr class="item-actions">
    <td colspan="100">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Remove or customize this code as per your requirement (Removing this code will remove delete button)

Note :- This code is working perfectly in magento 2.2.6